# Find a valid phone number using regular expression in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, python-re

```
phn1='412-1114-1234'

if re.search("\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}",phn1):
  print('It is a phone number')

else:
  print('It is not a phone number')
```

**Output:** It is not a phone number

But, when I pass the input:

```
phn1='4123-111-1234'
```

**Output:** It is a phone number

What is wrong in the code that I get a wrong output in the second phone number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It [matches](https://regex101.com/r/8iEIyU/1) `123-111-1234` (Everything except the first digit). Change your regex to: `^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$` to make sure it only matches the whole input ([example](https://regex101.com/r/QxrJKB/1)).

Comment: Or set bounds \b\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}b\ if the complete input should not be matched

Answer (score 0):

It is the `search` method behaviour, try `match` instead. When you try to search, it finds a match from `123-111-1234` this part. For more information: [search vs match](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#search-vs-match)

Comment: You would also need to include an end marker `$` to avoid matching `123-123-1234xyz` for example